# Equivalent MemSQL query for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, singlestore

Anybody could please help me in converting below MySQL query to MemSQL query.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `schema`, TABLE_NAME AS `name`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (N'Record')
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
```

Need to solve the below error

> [Error code:1064 SQL state:42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (N'Record')AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'' at line 1

Comment: Looks like the collate clause isn't supported (there). Perhaps `lower(TABLE_NAME) = 'record'` instead?

Comment: `N'Record'` feels like SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax.. Edited seams it also works in MySQL.  ... "You can use N'literal' (or n'literal') to create a string in the national character set" source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: i searched in memsql docs it seams you can't dynamiclly use COLLATE  in SELECT like MySQL can ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html )  atleast i could not find it... it might be possible when you use a temporary table as workaround because it seams there you can define a COLLATE ? https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.5/create-table/

Comment: @RaymondNijland, The national character literal is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, and suported by most dbms products.

Comment: "The national character literal is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, and suported by most dbms products "Yes i readed that already @jarlh "Standard SQL defines NCHAR or NATIONAL CHAR"  source  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html.. But not all of us have access to a ANSI/ISO SQL standard document...

Comment: @RaymondNijland, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `schema`, TABLE_NAME AS `name`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('Record')
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test';
```

which is case-sensitive, or

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `schema`, TABLE_NAME AS `name`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE lower(TABLE_NAME) IN ('record')
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test';
```

which is case-insensitive.

The COLLATE clause isn't supported there, and N'string' isn't supported.